# c# Lambda expression to VB.Net

Tags: c#, vb.net, lambda, fo-dicom

I want to convert

```
cfind.OnResponseReceived = (DicomCFindRequest rq, DicomCFindResponse rp) => {
    Console.WriteLine("Study UID: {0}", rp.Dataset.Get<string>(DicomTag.StudyInstanceUID));
};
```

to VB.Net

but,
neither

```
AddHandler cfind.OnResponseReceived, AddressOf onResponse
```

nor

```
AddHandler cfind.OnResponseReceived, Sub(rq, rp)
        onCFindResponse(rq, rp)
End Sub
```

thing works..
How can I convert it?

Comment: The action to be performed isn't equivalent - have you refactored the original C# Console.WriteLine action into a separate `Sub`?

Comment: It is an assignment, not an event subscription.  Note the =, there is no +=. Using AddHander is therefore not correct.  Assignment works the same in VB.NET, you use =.  Use Sub, not Function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be the equivalent VB.NET:

```
cfind.OnResponseReceived = Sub(rq As DicomCFindRequest, rp As DicomCFindResponse) 
    Console.WriteLine("Study UID: {0}", rp.Dataset.[Get](Of String)(DicomTag.StudyInstanceUID))

End Sub
```

Comment: Since the method doesn't return anything it should be a `Sub`, not a `Function`.

Comment: @visualvincent you are right, thanks. Updated the answer.